# Get specific info out of json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

How can I get only "coords" data out of my json object in jquery? And for each object its own coords?

Example of returned json from php as shown in console:

```
[  
  {  
    "id":"7",
    "name":"EXAMPLE",
    "address":"example adress",
    "coords":"96.0,17.0"
  },
  {  
    same here etc.
  }
]
```

EDIT: Problem is I can't access json object in a way you all recommended. If I type `object[0]` I get "[" if I type `object[1]` I get "{" then I get all the other characters in a sequence '"', "i", "d", etc.

I do my console log in a sucessfull ajax call like so:

```
.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data[2]);
});
```

And my php returns data like so:

```
echo json_encode($myData);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php - this is probably what you're after

Comment: `json_decode` function... check for it.

Comment: I think OP is asking how to get values from the object at the Javascript side.

Comment: @LazyPeon Refere this link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data coming back is just a string, so you need to do one of 2 things to get it into JSON format:

- in your `.ajax` call, set the option `dataType: 'json'` alongside the `url`, `data` etc parameters ( `$.ajax({ url: 'x.php', dataType: 'json' ... }).done(function...` )
- manually parse the JSON in your `.done()` function ( `.done(function(data) { data = $.parseJSON(data); ... });` )

This will convert into it a JSON format, where my original answer below applied.

---

Since your JSON is an array at the outermost level (`[ ]`), you can access the first-level items with array notation (eg. `[0]`). Inside that, you have an object (`{ }`) so you need dot-notation from there (eg. `[0].coords`).

Assuming your variable is called `myJson` you can get at the first coords with `myJson[0].coords`, the second set with `myJson[1].coords`, etc. You can loop over `myJson` to get all `coords` in a loop.

Comment: I should mention I get this data as a sucessfull ajax call, in my php frunction I write "echo json_encode($vsi_kraji);" and if I do console log in my jquery page I get: "undefined"

Comment: @LazyPeon show your AJAX handler. Typically your "success" function for the AJAX call should look something like `success: function(response) {` - in this case, `response` in this example is the `myJson` variable from my answer

Comment: I updated the question to show what I mean.

Comment: @LazyPeon answer updated to cover everything you should need :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can access `coords` this way:

```
objs[0].coords
```

`coords` is a member of the first object in the `objs` array.